# I can't get the specific field in csv file

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

just want to ask... why i can't get the Field 16 data? here's my code to get the data in csv file using codeigniter

this is in my controller:

```
public function index()
{
       $this->load->library('csvreader');

       $filePath = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Datacast\pdw_table.csv';

       $data['csvData'] = $this->csvreader->parse_file($filePath);

       die();
       echo '<pre>';
       print_r($data);
       die();
       echo '</pre>';

       $this->load->view('myform', $data);
}
```

this is my view:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
        <th>
                <td>Field 1</td>
                <td>Field 2</td>
                <td>Field 3</td>
                <td>Field 16</td>
        </th>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
                <?php foreach($csvData as $field)
                    {?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $field['Field 1']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $field['Field 2']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $field['Field 3']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $field['Field 16']; ?></td>
                    </tr>

                <?php }?>
        </tbody>

    </table>
```

everytime i print_r the $data in controller here's the output

```
Array
(
[csvData] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Field 1] => Myanmar
                [Field 2] => MPT_ONE
                [Field 3] => B7VIET-STP-0
                [] => 
                [Field 4] => 0
                [Field 5] => A
                [Field 6] => 1
                [Field 7] => HW_SX/SPC
                [Field 8] => STP
                [Field 9] => 4.28.1
                [Field 10] => 8417
                [Field 11] => VINAPHONE (Vietnam)/STP
                [Field 12] => STP
                [Field 13] => 4.104.3
                [Field 14] => 9027
                [Field 15] => HNI/VTI-YGN/MPT 30N001  (Vietnam-1)
                [Field 16
] => 1.1.1



            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Field 1] => Myanmar
                [Field 2] => MPT_ONE
                [Field 3] => B7VIET-STP-1
                [] => 
                [Field 4] => 0
                [Field 5] => A
                [Field 6] => 1
                [Field 7] => HW_SX/SPC
                [Field 8] => STP
                [Field 9] => 4.28.1
                [Field 10] => 8417
                [Field 11] => VINAPHONE (Vietnam)/STP
                [Field 12] => STP
                [Field 13] => 4.104.4
                [Field 14] => 9028
                [Field 15] => HCN/VTI-YGN/MPT 30N002 (Vietnam-2)
                [Field 16
] => 1.1.1


            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [Field 1] => Myanmar
                [Field 2] => MPT_ONE
                [Field 3] => LKBELGA1
                [] => 
                [Field 4] => 0
                [Field 5] => A
                [Field 6] => 1
                [Field 7] => DMS_NPT/SPC
                [Field 8] => STP
                [Field 9] => 4.28.3
                [Field 10] => 8419
                [Field 11] => BELGACOM-Belgium/STP
                [Field 12] => STP
                [Field 13] => 2.13.1
                [Field 14] => 4201
                [Field 15] => BRUSSELS-YANGON30N001
                [Field 16
] => 1.1.2


            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [Field 1] => Myanmar
                [Field 2] => MPT_ONE
                [Field 3] => LKSOFT1
                [] => 
                [Field 4] => 0
                [Field 5] => A
                [Field 6] => 1
                [Field 7] => DMS_NPT/SPC
                [Field 8] => STP
                [Field 9] => 4.28.3
                [Field 10] => 8419
                [Field 11] => SOFTBANK-Japan/STP
                [Field 12] => STP
                [Field 13] => 4.85.1
                [Field 14] => 8873
                [Field 15] => CHB/SBT-YGN30N002
                [Field 16
] => 1.1.2

            )
```

here is the output in var_dump()

```
array(1) {
["csvData"]=>
array(37) {
  [0]=>
 array(18) {
  ["Field 1"]=>
  string(7) "Myanmar"
  ["Field 2"]=>
  string(7) "MPT_ONE"
  ["Field 3"]=>
  string(12) "B7VIET-STP-0"
  [""]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Field 4"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["Field 5"]=>
  string(1) "A"
  ["Field 6"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["Field 7"]=>
  string(9) "HW_SX/SPC"
  ["Field 8"]=>
  string(3) "STP"
  ["Field 9"]=>
  string(6) "4.28.1"
  ["Field 10"]=>
  string(4) "8417"
  ["Field 11"]=>
  string(23) "VINAPHONE (Vietnam)/STP"
  ["Field 12"]=>
  string(3) "STP"
  ["Field 13"]=>
  string(7) "4.104.3"
  ["Field 14"]=>
  string(4) "9027"
  ["Field 15"]=>
  string(35) "HNI/VTI-YGN/MPT 30N001  (Vietnam-1)"
  ["Field 16"]=>
  string(5) "1.1.1"
  [" 
"]=>


  string(2) "
"

}
[1]=>
array(18) {
  ["Field 1"]=>
  string(7) "Myanmar"
  ["Field 2"]=>
  string(7) "MPT_ONE"
  ["Field 3"]=>
  string(12) "B7VIET-STP-1"
  [""]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Field 4"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["Field 5"]=>
  string(1) "A"
  ["Field 6"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["Field 7"]=>
  string(9) "HW_SX/SPC"
  ["Field 8"]=>
  string(3) "STP"
  ["Field 9"]=>
  string(6) "4.28.1"
  ["Field 10"]=>
  string(4) "8417"
  ["Field 11"]=>
  string(23) "VINAPHONE (Vietnam)/STP"
  ["Field 12"]=>
  string(3) "STP"
  ["Field 13"]=>
  string(7) "4.104.4"
  ["Field 14"]=>
  string(4) "9028"
  ["Field 15"]=>
  string(34) "HCN/VTI-YGN/MPT 30N002 (Vietnam-2)"
  ["Field 16"]=>
  string(5) "1.1.1"
  [" 
"]=>


  string(2) "
"

}
```

i don't know why the data of Field 16 is entered..

Comment: There is some strange newline after "Field 16"

Comment: yes and i can't find it

Comment: i have already check the csv content if there's an enter or something space but there's nothing wrong in the data

Comment: Can you do a **`var_dump()`** on the variable and post it here ?

Comment: array(1) {
  ["csvData"]=>
  array(37) {
    [0]=>
    array(17) {
      ["Field 13"]=>
      string(7) "4.104.3"
      ["Field 14"]=>
      string(4) "9027"
      ["Field 15"]=>
      string(35) "HNI/VTI-YGN/MPT 30N001  (Vietnam-1)"
      ["Field 16
"]=>
      string(7) "1.1.1
"
    }

here is the output of var_dump

Comment: still in the "Field 16" there is an entered

Comment: So, there is a space in the end of the field name, **`... ["Field 16 "]=> ...`**, Did you notice ? May be it is coming fron the CSV file.

Comment: Hi @IJas the output above is the current output of var_dump()

Comment: as you can see there is still a strange newline

Comment: Ya, What I was telling is unlike other fields, "Field 16" has a white-space after "16". Did you notice that ?

Comment: yes i have already fix it. thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a white-space in **`"[Field 16 "]`**. Fix it in the CSV. This will solve your problem.